# Can I execute multiple lines sudo commands?

Tags: command-line

This question relates to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/635507). If I paste the @kyodake 's suggested code, all at once in the terminal would it work?

Or should I go line by line?

Comment: @Ravan that's not true. A newline works just as well. Were it not for `sudo` requiring a password and for the OP of the linked answer including `#`, the commands could be copy-pasted directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's several approaches to letting multiple commands run with `sudo`.

The first one suits your use-case best. Others are added for the sake of exploring alternatives; they may not suit your particular need, but may come in handy to you in the future or other users.

**Approach #1: Cleanest and simplest**

Put everything into a script, for example `myscript.sh`, make the file executable with `chmod 755 myscript.sh`, and run that script with `sudo myscript.sh`

**Approach #2: long string of commands**

You need something with superuser privileges to run multiple commands. That would be shell, ( any shell for that matter, `bash` or `sh` ) . Shells have a `-c` flag, which tells them to run a command or a set of commands separated by a semicolon `;`. Simple example: `sudo bash -c 'apt-get update; apt-get upgrade'`. In particular, kyodake's answer can be re-done like so:

```
sudo bash -c 'apt-get update;apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan mate-desktop; aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(mate-desktop))))';aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(mate-desktop))))';aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(mate-desktop))))';apt-get install --reinstall mate-desktop;deborphan;apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan);deborphan --libdevel;apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel);deborphan --find-config;dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config);apt-get autoremove;apt-get clean;reboot'
```

Lengthy ? Yes. This approach works better when you need to run just a few commands with sudo.

**Approach #3: playing with sudo timeout**

By default, the `sudo` privilege times out after 15 minutes. So if you are certain all those commands won't take that long, you could run the first command with `sudo` and will be prompted for password; for all the subsequent commands you won't be prompted, but you still need to type `sudo`.

**Approach #4: using root shell**

As kyodake suggested himself in the answer, log-in to a root shell with `sudo -i` to use the root privilege until you `exit`. Note, that this is not recommended for security reasons. Unless you are 100% certain you will remember to log out once you are done working and no-one will get into your root shell, then... use this approach at your discretion.

Comment: "By default, `sudo` privilege timesout after 15 minutes" - that doesn't mean that all commands will be executed with `sudo` privilieges for 15 minutes, it only means that you won't have to type password each time you use `sudo`.

Comment: @gronostaj noted, already edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

#### *Copy-pasting the script will work*, and the commands will be executed one after the other;

However the problem here are the `$` / `#` characters at the start of each line, which would break each command; *removing them is mandatory before running the script in any way*.

I think the fastest / most direct way to do this would be to process it and to run it at the same time using the following method:

- Selecting the script, skipping the first line, as it is (i.e. including the `#` characters at the start)
- Copying the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Typing `sed 's/^.//' <<EOF | sudo bash`
- Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Pasting the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Typing `EOF`
- Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> again

Advantages against creating a script on purpose and running it:

1. It's quicker
2. There's no need to create any file
3. There's no need to process the script to remove the `$` / `#` characters

Here's an example using this script:

```bsh
# whoami
# echo command1
# echo command2
# echo command3
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ % sed 's/^.//' <<EOF | sudo bash
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ pipe heredoc> # whoami
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ pipe heredoc> # echo command1
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ pipe heredoc> # echo command2
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ pipe heredoc> # echo command3
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ pipe heredoc> EOF
root
command1
command2
command3
```